# Looking for opposite of tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: to detect when cell is being "un"-displayed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to detect when a table view cell is going off of the screen? The opposite of tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:, like tableView:willHideCell:forRowAtIndexPath: would be great, but obviously it doesn't exist.

The reason I'd like to detect this is because whenever a new cell is shown, I'm downloading images to place in that cell, but if the user is simply scrolling by the cell and not viewing it, I would like to cancel the download of those images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you won't need this, because the table view will usually always display the same number of cells, so a cell that goes offscreen will immediately be reused and in this case, the easiest approach would be to cancel the download after you dequeue the cell.

If you have a lot of different cell identifiers, this may not be the case though. One method I could think of would be to override `willMoveToSuperview:` in your `UITableViewCell` subclass and check the `superview` parameter for nil (which means that it has been removed from the view hierarchy).

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I'm not re-using my cells so I couldn't stop the download once the cell was re-used. What I did was set the tag of the cell to the row of the tableview that it's displaying, and kept all of the images in an array. If the superview of the cell was set to nil (it was removed from the view), I used the tag of the cell and the array of images to cancel the requested image download.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply do that after you deque a cell from the tableview.
As soon a cell pops of the screen it will be reused.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but if you look at Apple's [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Classes_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_12) sample, they delay starting the download of an image until scrolling ends:

```
if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO)
{
    [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: I tried using this, but the dragging and decelerating properties seem to always be YES once I drag and let go in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's 'didEndDisplaying'

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618036-collectionview